# i want key value when there is change in it's child firebase and javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

structure of my firebase db is like below image
[image of my firebase DB stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuWOh.png)

whenever thare is new message it will be added under particular id like in image it is "59a004ce9bfedb3f50ff2ec5" id
so every new message will create new node under perticuler id's goup_messages.

i want to get perticuler id whenever there is new message in it.

i have use

```
var getvalue = firebase.database().ref('foram-ec60c/' +userId+ '/goup_massages/');
        getvalue.once('value', function(snapshot) {});
    }
```

but i don't know how to get value of id?

i have use javascript to add data in firebase DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the id, try the following:

```
var getvalue = firebase.database().ref('foram-ec60c/' +userId+ '/goup_massages/');
getvalue.once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var keys=child.key;
   });
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

Comment: var getvalue1 = firebase.database().ref('foram-ec60c/');
  getvalue1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var keys=child.key;
    alert("key"+snapshot.key);
   });
  });

i used this but it will give me all key of db. what i want is key of child which was newly addded

Comment: use once instead of on